# MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks inheritance of variables from MSBuild main project file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

Case:
When I build from MSBuild (with VS Build Tools 2017) I don't get any value for $(ExtensionTasksPath) variable     
from main msbuild file, when I build with integrated VS MSBuild value is passed from main file to MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks, is that expected behavior and why does it happen? I don't use any properties for the sake of testing that particular case.

Comment: Do you use two msbuild tools to test the same .proj file? like: msbuild under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin and msbuild under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin.

Comment: On my side, I add a <message> target to output the value of $(ExtensionTasksPath), and both them works to get and show the value. Could you share the details how you test the case?(changes in .proj and msbuild versions) A reply would be expected.

Comment: The $(ExtensionTasksPath) property is defined in your .proj file. And we can't get the value from the A.xxproj unless we define it in .proj file. So i wonder whether you use same project to test.

Comment: Hi @Lance Li-MSFT, yes I am using both scenarios but on separate VMs. I have the main proj main.targets.msbuild and within it in properties encapsulation I have :<ExtensionTasksPath Condition="'$(ExtensionTasksPath)'==''">$(SourceHome)\Dependencies\MSBuild\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.9.1\</ExtensionTasksPath>  followed by <Import Project="$(ExtensionTasksPath)MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" /> and then in <Target Name="Publish" DependsOnTargets="Build"> I am simply calling  <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip from the extension pack.

Comment: The problem is that in MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks I have:     `<PropertyGroup>
        <BuildPath Condition="'$(BuildPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</BuildPath>
        <ExtensionTasksPath Condition="Exists('$(BuildPath)\..\..\BuildBinaries\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll')">$(BuildPath)\..\..\BuildBinaries\</ExtensionTasksPath>
        <ExtensionTasksPath Condition="'$(ExtensionTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\</ExtensionTasksPath>
    </PropertyGroup>` an the zip task

Comment: `<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(ExtensionTasksPath)MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip"/>` The problem is when I am using building with msbuild from visual studio enterprise there is no problem to process that task, when I process it with buildtools one that variable seems to be empty or having another value than the expected. So my workaround is to simply remove the property and remove the variable from the using statement and leave the file only like:  `<UsingTask AssemblyFile="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip"/>`

Comment: Hi friend, have you copied the entire solution folder to the machine where only uses VS build tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that expected behavior and why does it happen?

I think it's not we expect.As I test on a VM, the msbuild from VS Build Tools2017 get the same value as what we can get in msbuild from VS IDE.

> For the reason of this behavior I have some suggestions to help trouble
>   shooting:

1.First of all, make sure both two scenarios builds successfully.

2.As you mentioned above, you runs them in separate VMs, make sure the two file under test are the same and entire solution folder.(The package folder under solution directory makes sense)

3.Check in the .xxproj file, check if exists `<Import Project="..\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.9.1\build\net40\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.targets" ...>`

I've found the `$(ExtensionTasksPath)` property is defined in `MSBuild.Extension.Pack.targets` file, and this file is imported into .xxproj file by `<Import>` tag.

Have a look at pics below from my sample project which install MSBuild.Extension.Pack by nuget:
[image]
After my project install the extension bu nuget, there is an Import sentence in csproj file, open it we can find:

[image]

The value of $(ExtensionTasksPath) in defined here. So i guess you may have sth missing with the targets file or the import sentense or have sth corrupt this property.

> In summary:

1.keep the entire solution folder could be the best suggestion.
2.And if it not works, add a script below to your .xxproj file can work:

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <ExtensionTasksPath> Absolute path of your MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll</ExtensionTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It will overwrite values from  tag and no matter where you put the assembly, just add the absolute path can work.
It my answer is helpful, please give me a feedback. And any update please feel free to contact me.

Comment: your answer definitely answers the questions if this should happen or no, so I voted as accepted answer, based on your further guidelines I will try to narrow the issue, but so far i can't, I will most likely stick with absolute path/relative path resolution as you suggested (as I am currently0.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If there has any update, feel free to contact me. And sometimes an absolute path could be a better way for issues with path.